# Padding numbers in GNU Makefiles

Tags: makefile, padding

In GNU Make you have a list of numbers:

```
NUMBERS = 8 9 10
```

How can you pad them with leading zeroes?

```
NUMBERS = 08 09 10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that the Make (at least GNU Make) does not have functions to deal well with this type of data. You can go wild and use the shell (only on unixes):

```
NUMBERS = 8 9 10
NUMBERS2=$(foreach v,$(NUMBERS),$(shell printf '%02d' $(v)))
all:
    echo $(NUMBERS2)
```

Will print:

```
08 09 10
```

Answer (score 2):

If each number is not too big, you could implement it as follows:

```
__seq = $(foreach i,$(seq1),$(addprefix $i,$1))
seq1 := 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
seq2 := $(call __seq,$(seq1))
seq3 := $(call __seq,$(seq2))

# Args:
#   1. Padding (1, 2, or 3)
#   2. Numbers
pad = $(strip \
    $(foreach n,$2, \
        $(if $(subst 0,,$n), \
            $(word $n,$(wordlist 2,$(words $(seq$1)),$(seq$1))), \
            $(firstword $(seq$1)))))

NUMBERS := 8 9 10

all:
    echo $(call pad,2,$(NUMBERS))
```